# Oracle: Select Query to filter over date column by changing its format from varchar to date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, varchar

I have a table Oracle DB which gives information about the various trouble conditions faced by the different customer in our services on a daily basis.

What I am trying to do is to calculate the total count of different trouble conditions, for example, cellular offline, broadband offline, camera not responding, etc. per day reported by all customer.

The problem is that the trouble condition starting date column is of type varchar, so filtering and grouping is not giving the required result.

Please suggest some solution, I am not allowed to add a new column. I am just allowed to run a select command.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
select trouble_condition_start_date, count(1) from trouble_tables
where trouble_condition_start_date >= '11/1/2019'
and trouble_condition = 'Camera - Not Responding'
group by trouble_condition_start_date
order by trouble_condition_start_date
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already notice, it's a bad idea to store a date as text in a database. Anyway, you can always convert it on-the-fly with `TO_DATE`. E.g.:

```
select
  to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as start_date, 
  count(*)
from trouble_tables
where to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= date '2019-11-01'
  and trouble_condition = 'Camera - Not Responding'
group by to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
order by to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Same thing with a `WITH` clause for better readability:

```
with better_table as 
(
  select t.*, to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as start_date
  from trouble_tables t
)
select start_date, count(*)
from better_table
where start_date >= date '2019-11-01'
  and trouble_condition = 'Camera - Not Responding'
group by start_date
order by start_date;
```

Comment: select trouble_condition_start_date, count(1) from adc_troubles
where to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= date '2019-11-01'
and trouble_condition = 'Video Device - Not Responding'
group by trouble_condition_start_date
order by trouble_condition_start_date ASC;

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Of course you must specify the appropriate date format used in trouble_condition_start_date.  `'mm/dd/yyyy'` is just an example.

Comment: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
Error at Line: 2 Column: 67

Comment: 12/14/2019
12/16/2019
1/12/2020
12/10/2019
1/13/2020
1/14/2020
1/8/2020
1/13/2020
1/13/2020

Comment: This is `'mm/dd/yyyy'`. I see no problem with this. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=faf587e20f2406f3638545b3789e338a There is probably a string in that table that doesn't match this format.

Comment: thanks for your response still issue not resolved i m figuring out more

Comment: As of Oracle 12c you can use `ON CONVERSION ERROR` to find the faulty rows: `select * from adc_troubles where to_date(trouble_condition_start_date default null on conversion error, 'mm/dd/yyyy') is null;`.

Comment: till here the query is working and giving result but group by giving error :select to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), trouble_condition_start_date from adc_troubles 
where trouble_condition = 'Video Device - Not Responding' and 
to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= date '2019-11-01'

Comment: but for this : select to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), count(1) from adc_troubles 
where trouble_condition = 'Video Device - Not Responding' and 
to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= date '2019-11-01'
group by to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
order by to_date(trouble_condition_start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy');    error : ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Look for the row(s) that contain an invalid date. It can happen that with two almost identical queries one works and the other doesn't. It's just good or bad luck. One query may look at trouble_condition first and dismiss the row with the invalid date while the other looks at trouble_condition_start_date first and crashes at the same row. Find the invalid date(s).

Comment: Do you have Oracle 12 or higher? Have you tried the ON CONVERSION ERROR query?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer 18_2

Comment: while executing select * from adc_troubles 
where to_date( trouble_condition_start_date default null on conversion error, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) is null; error : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 45

Comment: It is strange that you are getting all these unexpected errors. As you can see, there is nothing wrong with this query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8c893913be3fa0aa6a5eb548a6bfc44. But wait, ... Oracle SQL Developer is just a tool to select from the database. But which version is your *DBMS*? Check with `select * from v$version;`.